# Using Audacity to Record Skype with External Mic

Tags: skype, recording, soundflower

i am using Audacity to (attempt to) record a skype conversation.  I am using an external mic.

when i attempt to record skype (via soundflower) in audacity, i only hear the skype output.  I can hear the caller on the other end, but not me.  this is true if i use the external mic or the built in mic.

i would like to have ideally separate tracks into audacity, one for my mic and one for skype output.  but i would be happy if they came in as one track too.  thank you!

Comment: @konqui - make it to an answer :)

Comment: done, now it is an answer.

Comment: Have you tried running two instances of Audacity simultaneously? OSX will let you do that.

Answer (score 1):

For me sometimes Soundflower (i think is made to just do simple matching of one input to one output) alone just wasn't enough, specially when it comes to audio routing.

Then i use Jack jackosx.com, there i can also do things like route one input to two or even more outputs.

Sometimes i also use a combination of both.